# Solve equations and rejecting all of answers except one of them?

Tags: equation-solving

I have the following code:

```
n = 3; 
EE[1] = 2*u[1] + 4*u[2] - 5*u[3] - 6; 
EE[2] = 3*u[1] + u[3]^2 + 5; 
EE[3] = 6*u[1] + u[2] - u[3] + 7; 
NSolve[Table[EE[i], {i, n}], Table[u[i], {i, n}]]
```

Output is:

```
{{u[1] -> -1.5485537190082643 - 0.027234351914181974*I, u[2] -> 2.359504132231405 + 0.7625618535970953*I, 
   u[3] -> 0.06818181818181807 + 0.5991557421120034*I}, {u[1] -> -1.5485537190082643 + 0.027234351914181974*I, 
   u[2] -> 2.359504132231405 - 0.7625618535970953*I, u[3] -> 0.06818181818181807 - 0.5991557421120034*I}}
```

I want to accept just one of them arbitrary. Please consider for every system of this kind I want to accept just one of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would `RandomChoice` help you?

Comment: @David Baghdasaryan Many thanks. Your comment solved my problem.